# onViewableItemsChanged isn't called in a nested ScrollView (React-Native)

Tags: react-native, scrollview, flatlist

I have a ScrollView for the entire screen and inside it there is a FlatList. when I place `onViewableItemsChanged` inside the flatlist it does not work, unless I make the ScrollView a normal View.

What should I do to solve this ?

Comment: Hi, can you please share the code or screenshot?